# Conflicting enums

Tags: c++, c

What happens if two different libs define the same enum and I need to use both libs in the same project?

enum Month {January=0, February, ..., December}

Thank you.

P.S. It is C. No namespaces. I won't be able to keep them separated. Need some workaround.

What it the enum linkage? Internal or external? C libs used in C++ project. C++ tag applies.

Comment: Hope that the two libs use separate namespaces?

Comment: This is really no different to multiple conflicting definitions of types, variables, or functions.

Comment: Is this C or C++? They are not one language.

Comment: Nasal demons, obviously.

Comment: C code used in C++ is in the global namespace and `enum`s aren't really either internal or external. They apply if you declare them. There isn't a name to put in the binary, so it generally doesn't matter.

Comment: I still removed the C++ tag because even if you use it in a C++ project, the code is still C. In any case, the C++ answer would be "use namespaces".

Comment: I realize this doesn't solve your problem, but perhaps you could ask the authors of these packages what they were smoking when they came up with these enums. I can't think of any viable reason for them to exist at the source level unless the intent is to hard-code calendar **data** into source files. In other words, aside from this, what possible use could `January` or `December` have in a source file?

Comment: @In silico. C++ tag applies. See Nawaz's answer.

Comment: @Maxpm: The behavior is well defined - it's just that unless you jump through hoops you won't even get a successful compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimate magic evil wizard workaround: if namespaces don't help (for whatever reason), and you absolutely can't avoid including both definitions in the same file, use a macro:

```
#define Month File_A_Month
#include "file_a.h"
#define Month File_B_Month
#include "file_b.h"
#undef Month
```

In the file, never use `Month`, only `File_A_Month` or `File_B_Month`. I'm not certain of the standards-correctness of this practice.

You might have to define all the enum members similarly to prevent clashes, and you probably want to put this evil hackery in a file called `files_a_and_b.h`. Of course, in your case the definitions are identical, so you shouldn't need to resort to this, but I'm leaving this answer here for less fortunate posterity.

Comment: Identical enumeration constant names will cause name clashes even if the definitions are identical.  But, as mentioned, applying the macro hack to each of the enum names will do the trick.

Answer (score 12):

> C libs used in C++ project. C++ tag applies

Since they're used in C++ projects, then you can use namespace when including them in C++ code as:

```
// C files
//libone.h 
enum Month {January=0, February, ..., December}

//libtwo.h
enum Month {January=0, February, ..., December}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//C++ files

//lib.hpp
namespace LibOne 
{
     #include "libone.h"
}
namespace LibTwo 
{
     #include "libtwo.h"
}

//Usage in C++
LibOne::Month m1 = LibOne::January;
LibTwo::Month m2 = LibTwo::January;
```

Comment: @pic11: I don't know how your code structure is. But one thing is sure, whenever you add a new library to your C++ projects, which cause name-conflicts, then you can always include the new library in a different namespace.

Comment: I am writing C++ API and the same enum is already defined in my lib's namespace. The user code can pass enum value to my API which in turn passes the same value to C API.

Answer (score 4):

Neither the `enum` itself nor the enumeration constants are objects, so they don't have any linkage at all - in this respect, they're like `struct` tags or `typedef` names.

This means that you have two workarounds:

- Ensure that the conflicting headers are never, directly or indirectly, `#include`d in the same translation unit (`.c` file); or
- Launder one or both of the headers to change the conflicting names.

The header laundering can be done either by creating a private copy of the header with the names changed, or using the preprocessor as in [Chris Lutz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285872/conflicting-enums/6285991#6285991).

Comment: +1. Quote: *Ensure that the conflicting headers are never, directly or indirectly, #included in the same translation unit*

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, the two are in different namespaces.

Otherwise, you may be able to avoid including both definitions in a single compile unit.

**EDIT**: Okay, you're in C, so you don't have namespaces, and it sounds like you want to reference both definitions in the same compile unit. Next steps:

- Do they have exactly the same definition?
- Do you have any influence on the names in either of the libraries?
- Are you sure you can't hide references to one of them in a different compile unit?

Comment: The definitions are identical.

Comment: @pic: If the definitions are identical, then there should be no problem.

Comment: @Oli. Yes, no problem as long as definitions from two libs are not included into the same translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

> Quote: *I am writing C++ API and the same enum is already defined in my lib's namespace.*

So one of these enums is inside the namespace of your library? Then you should not have a problem. The C library you are using is in the global namespace, your library has its own namespace, and as long as you do the Right Thing, the two will never collide. The following is perfectly valid, I believe:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "foo.h"
  // enum Month { January, February, December };
}

namespace mylib {
  enum Month { Chaos, Discord, Confusion, Bureaucracy, Aftermath };

  Month convert(::Month c_month);
}

void foo() {
  ::Month month = December;
  mylib::Month result = mylib::convert(month);
}
```