# Arduino linker error when using namespaces

Tags: c++, arduino, linker, namespaces

I am trying to use two libraries with very similar code, and one enum is giving a naming conflict.  Following [advice I found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285913/163177) I used a `namespace` which resolved the naming conflict but produces a linker error.

Minimum example:

```
#include <INA219_WE.h>

namespace Ina226 {
  #include <INA226_WE.h>
}

// INA219 (Solar Panel) setup
INA219_WE ina219(0x44);

//INA226 (Battery) setup
Ina226::INA226_WE ina226(0x40);
```

Error message:

```
sketch\Solar.ino.cpp.o:(.literal.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_ina219+0x14): undefined reference to `Ina226::INA226_WE::INA226_WE(int)'

sketch\Solar.ino.cpp.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_ina219':

D:\dev\Arduino\Solar/Solar.ino:14: undefined reference to `Ina226::INA226_WE::INA226_WE(int)'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
```

I cant tell if I am misusing `namespace` or if there is some quirk I need to address in the compiler.

Comment: Removed C tag and replaced with C++. Because above is C++ not C.

Comment: It does not work this way. You placed declarations from the file into the namespace, but definitions left in the global namespace.

Comment: S.M.  what did the referenced StackOvervlow answer do that I did not?